# Discrete Math Set Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I came up a problem with for one of the question.
I have to proof if the following statement is true/false.

$$C\setminus(A\setminus B) = (C\setminus A)\cup(C\cap B)$$

I am a little confuse $C\setminus(A\setminus B)$.
I am not sure where to start.

Thanks guys.

Comment: what is C(A\B)?

Comment: I think it should read $C\setminus(A\setminus B)=(C\setminus A)\cup(C\cap B)$.... maybe?

Comment: yeah for some reason, it don't let me the us the \ between C and (A\B)

Answer (score 2):

Using the identity $X\setminus Y=X\cap Y^C$, where $Y^C$ is the compliment of $Y$:

$$C\setminus(A\setminus B) = C\cap (A\setminus B)^C= C\cap (A\cap B^C)^C=C\cap ( A^C \cup B) = (C\cap A^C)\cup(C\cap B)=(C\setminus A)\cup (C\cap B).$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint:  draw a Venn diagram for three mutually intersecting sets $A$, $B$, $C$.  Then shade in the region described by the LHS, and shade in the region described by the RHS.  Are they the same?  If so, then use the diagram to try to break down this region into smaller cases.  Or, write out a truth table.